# How do i deploy a React Project on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a react app on Heroku and whenever I load the page the failed to construct WebSocket error is Displayed. 
Is there a fix for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change your `ws://` URL to `wss://`.

Comment: How do I change it?

Comment: It's your code, not mine. Find where you set the websocket URL and change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first make a backup !

open this file :

```
./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js
```

go to line 60

now change var connection = new WebSocket to

```
var connection = new WebSocket(
  url.format({
    protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws', // this is important
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port: window.location.port,
    // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
    pathname: '/sockjs-node',
    slashes: true // add this line Babak
  })
);
```

maybe need stop your project and run npm start again